# Use parameters in validation

Tags: validation, yaml, symfony

In my Symfony3 application, I want to create a validation constraint, where the max length value can be set dynamically via the parameters file, somehow like this

### File `app/paramters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    ...
    entity_max_length: 5
```

### File `src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml`:

```
Acme\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity
    properties:
        name:
            - Length:
                max: '%entity_max_length%'
```

But it won't work this way. It simply marks all items as too long and gives an error message like

> Your field is too long. Limit is %entity_max_length% characters.

Is there a way to pass parameters into validation constraints in YAML?

Comment: For YAML, `'%entity_max_length%'` is just a string scalar that happens to have a percent sign at the beginning and end. There is no substitution done in YAML. What does the tag Symfony3 have to do with this?

Comment: I propose to write a [Custom Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) for this kind of requirement

Comment: paramters.yml and validation.yml are both files in a Symfony3 application. Thanks for the advice about the Custom Validaton. I knew about that but was curious if I could do it just using YAML.

Comment: I haven't seen a way to do it in the manner you have. I have only seen it done in the manner displayed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#basic-usage). Did you try using an import at the top of your validation.yml file to see if that works? `imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }` . To me it seems weird to have validation values and the validation constraints themselves in two different files.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel BTW Is this a single file with two comments? Or are these two files without proper separation. Independent of that: the first key below the line `# src/Acme/...` is a multiline scalar `Acme\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity name` is that what you want or is there a colon missing after `...MyEntity`?

Comment: @AndrewNolan Yes, that is the regular (static) way. I'm aware of this (and am using it extensively. But I'm looking for a way to set the value via the parameters file.

Comment: @Anthon These are two files in a Symfony3 application. No there is no colon missing. It is the notation for a Symfony3 validation file (cf. doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

Comment: By the way: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096342/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-validation-constraint-in-symfony2-in-yml (cannot vote to close as that question too has no answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a parameter to a validation constraint in Symfony2 - in yml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096342/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-validation-constraint-in-symfony2-in-yml)